# what to install in a linux operating system XAMPP or LAMP?

Tags: php, linux, web

Hi I am a newbie in web development and I want to know what should PHP server to install in my laptop with a linux operating system?

Comment: LAMP is XAMPP on linux. This question does not make much sense…

Comment: I would highly recommend trying Docker out, in the long run it's worth the effort.

Comment: How about including your Linux distro and version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Debian based distro (like Ubuntu) it is a good idea to install PhpMyAdmin, as this package includes all the necessary dependecies (Apache, MySQL and PHP). This would be a like one-click installer for a LAMP environment.

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

You can also install the single packages one by one if you don't need or like PhpMyAdmin on your system.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php7.0 mysql-server mysql-client
```

Comment: This could be a nifty shortcut.  I'd recommend running apt-get install with the simulate flag to get an idea of what it will do before blindly installing.

Answer (score 0):

xampp install on linux:

```
> wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.6.20/xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run
> sudo su
> chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run
> ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.20-0-installer.run
```